# Чем заменить Цикл While

Tags: golang

Как мне известно в `go` нет цикла `while` а можно ли его чем нибудь заменить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for с условием:

```
for bool_cond {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: bool_cond - это ваше условие из while, x < 10, например

Comment: Аааааааааа ясно